# How to encrypt the session cookie in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, session-cookies

Let us say I do something like this in my application:

```
session[user_id] = 1
```

According to the video I watched (referenced below): In rails 4:

- the session cookie by default is encoded but not encrypted.  Meaning:  The session cookie is not able to be altered because of the digest value.  If the savvy user alters the payload somehow then it will render the session cookie useless.
- Regarding the fact that the session cookie is encoded, but not encrypted.  Even though the savvy user cannot *successfully alter* the session cookie, the savvy user is able to still *read* the contents.

I know that the convention is to never store anything confidential in a cookie: whether that cookie is a regular cookie or a session cookie.  However, for added security:  How can one encrypt the session cookie so that its contents are not able to be read by that savvy user at all?

Furthermore: How can I changed the default behavior of the session cookie from being just encoded by default to being encrypted as well?

**Background:**  I worked through the Lynda.com course "Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training."  I got to the "Cookies and Sessions" video.

Also: [relevant rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the [relevant Rails Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html), This area provides the answer:

> If you only have secret_token set, your cookies will be signed, but not encrypted. This means a user cannot alter their user_id without knowing your app's secret key, but can easily read their user_id. This was the default for Rails 3 apps.
>
> If you have secret_key_base set, your cookies will be encrypted. This goes a step further than signed cookies in that encrypted cookies cannot be altered or read by users. This is the default starting in Rails 4.

`secret_key_base` is located in rails 4 by default in: `config/secrets.yml`.  So actually: in rails 4 the default actually is to encrypt session cookies.

Comment: what is wrong with my answer???

Comment: Your original answer was "Found the answer, will update with it" - this attracts downvotes. Avoid posting any answer until you've written the answer itself. You can always put a comment on your question while you're writing the answer instead.

Comment: @sjagr ok.  I just did that so as to save people the time from writing an answer because I figured out the answer to my own question, and was going to post the answer myself.

Answer (score 5):

According to what I read [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html):

> If you have secret_key_base set, your cookies will be encrypted. This goes a step further than signed cookies in that encrypted cookies cannot be altered or read by users. This is the default starting in Rails 4.